# How to get positions of element matches in a list in kdb?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

For instance, if I have a list `a:2 5 3 1`, I can match another list against it, say `b:3 5`, which matches the 3 at `a[2]` and the 5 at `a[1]`. I am interested in getting my hands on the indices `2 1`.

I tried `where 3 5 in 2 5 3 1` but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `?` for this:

```
q)2 5 3 1?3 5
2 1
```

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/search/#find

Comment: Thanks, however this doesn't appear to work in queries: `select b ? a from flip `a`b!(1 2 ; (3 2 1; 3 2 1))` gives the error: `rank`

Comment: note that `?` only returns the index of the first occurence. Sounds like this is what you want anyways, but worth noting. If you want all locations then something like `where each b=\:a`